# Checkout page is not working after upgrading Magento to 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento-1.9

I have upgraded my Magento to version 1.9.3.7.

On the checkout page, when I fill the billing information it does not continue the process of checkout.

I didn't find the error. Is anyone know where is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no error in console @Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like form key missing, please go to your theme and find billing.phtml inside persistence folder and add  form key

Comment: ok i will check @sunil

Comment: yes form key is missing...how to add form key and where ? @sunil

Comment: Thank you @sunil...i added form key in billing.phtml. its working now. :)